# Proof that $G = K \rtimes Q$ for some group $G$ if and only if

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the next definition:

Given a group G, we say that it is a semi-direct product of $K,Q$, if there is
$K_{1} \lhd G$ with a complement $Q_{1}$, such that $K_{1}\cong K$ and 
$Q_{1}\cong{Q}$.

Prove that $G = K \rtimes Q$ for some group $G$ if and only if there is a homomorphism $f:G\longrightarrow G$ such that $f^{2} = f$ and such that its kernel is isomorphic to K.

In the first sense I proposed the function

$f : G = K_{1}Q_{1} \longrightarrow G$ defined by $f(kq) = q$ with $k\in K_1$ and $q\in Q_1$, but I can't prove that it is an isomorphism.

In the second sense I proposed $K_{1}=Ker{f}$ and $Q_{1} = f(G)$, but I can´t prove that $G = K_{1}Q_{1}$

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Here's some background: http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~abartel/docs/Semi-direct%20products.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Lemma.** $G=K\rtimes Q$ if and only if there exists a homomorphism $f:G\to G$ such that $f^2=f$, $\ker(f)=K$ and $\mbox{im}(f)=Q$.

*Proof.*
$\Rightarrow$ Your idea was correct. Define

$$f:G\to G$$
$$f(kq)=q$$

This is a well defined homomorphism since $G=K\rtimes Q$ so every element in $G$ has a unique representation in the form $kq$, $k\in K$, $q\in Q$. The $f^2=f$ equality follows simply from the definition. Obviously $\mbox{im}(f)=Q$ and since for any $x\in K$ we have $f(x)=f(kq)=q$ so $f(x)=e$ if and only if $q=e$ and this is if and only if $x=kq\in K$. Thus $\ker(f)=K$.

$\Leftarrow$ Let $K=\ker(f)$ and $Q=\mbox{im}(f)$. First we will show that $K\cap Q=\{e\}$. Indeed, if $x\in K\cap Q$ then

$$f(x)=x\mbox{ since }x\in Q$$
$$f(x)=e\mbox{ since }x\in K$$

Thus $x=e$. Now pick $g\in G$. It follows that $f(f(g))=f(g)$ thus

$$f(f(g)g^{-1})=e$$

Therefore $f(g)g^{-1}\in K$, so $f(g)g^{-1}=k$ for some $k\in K$. Therefore

$$k^{-1}f(g)=g$$

and thus $g\in KQ$.

We've proven that $G$ is generated by $K, Q$ and that $K\cap Q=\{e\}$. Thus $G=K\rtimes Q$.